# A good HTML object model in Java?

Tags: java, html, api, object-model

I'm looking for an HTML object model in Java, capable of parsing HTML (not required) and containing all HTML elements (and CSS as well) in an elegant object model.

I'm looking for a pure java version of the Groovy's HTML builder.
(I have no luck on google with this request.)

I want to be able to perform stuff like:

```
HTML html = new HTML();
Body body = html.body();

Table table body.addTable(myCssStyle);
Row row = table.addRow("a", "b", "c").withCss(cssRowStyle);
```

and so on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Jakarta ECS](http://jakarta.apache.org/ecs/index.html) might be able to do what you want.

Comment: I wish I could +10 for this.  That is a cool little project.  Especially with the prospects for using it under Clojure which would be really cool!

Comment: Unfortunately Jakarta ECS is retired as of 2010-09-01.  It has been archived to the Apache Attic.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/):

**Example:**
*(Building some html)*

```
Document doc = Document.createShell("");

Element headline = doc.body().appendElement("h1").text("thats a headline");
Element pTag = doc.body().appendElement("p").text("some text ...");
Element span = pTag.prependElement("span").text("That's");

System.out.println(doc);
```

**Output:**

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <h1>thats a headline</h1>
  <p><span>That's</span>some text ...</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Documentation:**

- [Codebook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/)
- [API Documentation (JavaDoc)](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/)

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea: you could take a look at the source code of xhtmlrenderer project.
http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer//

It's not plain HTML (it's XHTML), but may be a good starting point, don't you think?

Comment: Well, this is an interesting project, but it's not really what I need.