# What is a good technique for markup (HTML) generation?

Tags: java, html, api, frameworks

Some time ago I asked here about a [good html object model in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119180/a-good-html-object-model-in-java). 
I received a good answer pointing to the [Element Construction Set](http://jakarta.apache.org/ecs/) project:

I used happily this API to quickly build some HTML reports.

When visiting the project site recently, I found that it has been moved to "The Apache Attic" and that the author of the project encourages its user **to switch to other techniques for markup generation.**

My question is about this last sentence:
**what is a good other technique for markup generation ?**

I'm not building an HTML client, I just need to generate some reports in HTML from server side data. I have considered some replacement tools but I can't find my next one:

- groovy and its markup builder
- free marker
- xslt
- jasper report

What I like with ECS is that it is purely in Java (no new syntax and concepts to learn, other project libs available), it is quite small, it contains definition for all commons html elements and properties (easy to use with auto completion, without having to have an HTML doc around -> good for server side developer with only basic knowledge of HTML)

At the moment I'm wasting time doing investigation, playing around with some potential replacer, but I would be glad to have feedback to help me refocus on doing my task.

What other techniques would you recommend for this kind of usage and having the same ease of use than ECS ?

Comment: So you want developers generate some HTML pages that contain reports? You might just use plain JSP along with HTML code completion and syntax highlighing within Eclipse (I'd say other major IDEs support that as well) - which also tells you whether you are missing a closing tag etc. To me it seems that with ECS you'd still have to have some knowledge of HTML and CSS, otherwise you'd not know what elements/styles to employ.

Comment: JSP are not very lightweight to embed: I will need a jsp compiler and  don't feel the syntax will be a gain... Velocity or FreeMarker sounds better in this area. ECS requires basic HTML/CSS knowledge, but autocompletion helps to refresh my memory.

Comment: Yes, velocity and freemarker are dwefinitely a better choice, but unfortunately I'm not aware of any editor that supports completion/highlighting for html as well as velocity/freemarker. However, speaking of Eclipse, you might be able to use them and open the files in an HTML/JSP editor - which does provide HTML code completion etc. but lacks velocity/freemarker support - and first create the HTML parts. Then you could switch the editor to fill in velocity/freemarker specific parts.

Comment: Intellij has a good support for at least freemarker. I'm just not very familiar with it yet and I'm still looking for the solution I want to adopt. I like template engine for very simple task, but once there is a lot of logic, I don't feel them very readable and maintanable.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, what works best is a templating mechanism and a function for escaping markup (handling `&lt;` `&amp;` `&quot;` and `&apos;` will do).  Pick any templating engine that supports basic control structures like loops and conditionals.

Don't bother with object models for generating HTML.

Comment: why should I "Don't bother with object models for generating HTML." ? GWT and other components based client API are successfully bothering with it :-)

Comment: GWT, JSF, and the like synchronise state between the browser and the server, so they needs some kind of mapping between the DOM and the component model.  You are only generating reports in one direction (if I understood correctly).  I think it's an extra effort to build a tree just for that, and it's not worth it.  Templates are easier.

Comment: Very true. The thing I'm not comfortable with using template (and JSP) is that it can become quite a mess when there is too much logic in it. Then I can introduce a 'presentation model' to avoid complex templates, but this is extra effort too. The other thing I don't like is the maintenance problem arising when the object model change.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 4 solutions.

The first one is probably the best one: https://j2html.com/

```
// https://j2html.com/examples.html
@Test
public void test() {
    String s = document(
        html(
            head(
                title("Title"),
                link().withRel("stylesheet").withHref("/css/main.css")),
            body(
                main(attrs("#main.content"),
                    h1("Heading!"))))).toString();
    assertEquals("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\">\n"
        + "<html>\n"
        + "  <head>\n"
        + "    <title>\n"
        + "      Title\n"
        + "    </title>\n"
        + "    <link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/css/main.css\">\n"
        + "  </head>\n"
        + "  <body>\n"
        + "    <main id=\"main\" class=\"content\">\n"
        + "      <h1>\n"
        + "        Heading!\n"
        + "      </h1>\n"
        + "    </main>\n"
        + "  </body>\n"
        + "</html>\n", JtidyTest.tidyHtml(s));
}
```

It does not support pretty-print. Use jtidy for that:

```
public static String tidyHtml(String inputHtml) {
    Properties oProps = new Properties();
    oProps.setProperty("new-blocklevel-tags", "main");

    Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
    tidy.setConfigurationFromProps(oProps);
    tidy.setXHTML(false);
    tidy.setDocType("loose");
    tidy.setQuiet(true);
    tidy.setShowWarnings(false);
    tidy.setTidyMark(false);
    tidy.setIndentContent(true);
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    tidy.parse(new StringReader(inputHtml), writer);
    return writer.toString().replace("\r", "");
}
```

The following two examples/solutions use only Java's own XML stuff and therefore don't provide explicit HTML support, which is a bit inconvenient.

From object model:

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();

    Element htmlElement = doc.createElement("html");
    htmlElement.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");
    doc.appendChild(htmlElement);

    Element headElement = doc.createElement("head");
    htmlElement.appendChild(headElement);

    Element titleElement = doc.createElement("title");
    titleElement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("The title of the page &"));
    headElement.appendChild(titleElement);

    assertEquals("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\n"
            + "<head>\n"
            + "<META http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">\n"
            + "<title>The title of the page &amp;</title>\n"
            + "</head>\n"
            + "</html>\n",
            transform(doc));
}

static String transform(Document doc) {
    try {
        DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(domSource, result);
        return writer.toString().replace("\r", "");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

Full code: https://github.com/jjYBdx4IL/java-evaluation/blob/master/src/test/java/tests/javax/xml/XhtmlGenTest.java

Directly to stream:

```
@Test
public void testGenerateXHTML() throws Exception {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
    XMLOutputFactory outputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
    XMLStreamWriter xml = outputFactory.createXMLStreamWriter(baos);

    xml.writeStartDocument();
    xml.writeStartElement("html");
    xml.writeDefaultNamespace("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");

    xml.writeStartElement("head");
    xml.writeStartElement("title");
    xml.writeCharacters("The title of the page");
    xml.writeEndElement();
    xml.writeEndElement();

    xml.writeEndElement();
    xml.writeEndDocument();

    assertEquals("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><head><title>The title of the page</title></head></html>",
            baos.toString("UTF-8"));
}
```

Full code: https://github.com/jjYBdx4IL/java-evaluation/blob/master/src/test/java/tests/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamWriterTest.java

You might also consider ECS, but it is retired and does not support implicit handling of special characters like &. I have updated it to compile with Java 8: https://github.com/jjYBdx4IL/misc/tree/master/ecs Not sure when I'll deploy it to maven central tho. I have also modified it to include javadoc, sources and debug symbols, all of which the existing distribution on maven central does not provide.

Comment: I don't see a convenient way to insert table with variable number of rows of data.