# html5 alternative to Jakarta ECS (or similar tools)?

Tags: java, html, api

i was wondering if there are any good html5 generation tools for Java, similar to the  [Jakarta ECS project](http://jakarta.apache.org/ecs/), which has long been retired. I see there are questions regarding programmatic html generation through java, but most of the answers refer to outdated tools that don´t fully support html5.

I refer to this question in particular: [A good HTML object model in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119180/a-good-html-object-model-in-java)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there's one: [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).

> jsoup implements the *WHATWG HTML5* specification, and parses HTML to
>   the same DOM as modern browsers do.
>
> - scrape and parse HTML from a URL, file, or string
> - find and extract data, using DOM traversal or CSS selectors
> - manipulate the HTML elements, attributes, and text
> - clean user-submitted content against a safe white-list, to prevent XSS attacks
> - output tidy HTML

**Example:**
*(Building some html)*

```
Document doc = Document.createShell("");

Element headline = doc.body().appendElement("h1").text("thats a headline");
Element pTag = doc.body().appendElement("p").text("some text ...");
Element span = pTag.prependElement("span").text("That's");

System.out.println(doc);
```

**Output:**

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <h1>thats a headline</h1>
  <p><span>That's</span>some text ...</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Documentation:**

- [Codebook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/)
- [API Documentation (JavaDoc)](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/)

Comment: Excelent find @ollo , works great